# Proof that $\vert\int_a^bf(t)dt\vert\le\int_a^b\vert f(t)\vert dt $ for complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

The following proof is given in my notes:
Write the complex integral $\int_a^bf(t)dt = Re^{i\theta}$
where
$$
R=\int_a^bf(t)dt. \quad(1)
$$
On the other hand,
$$
R=\int_a^be^{-i\theta}f(t)dt.\quad(2)
$$
Write $e^{-i\theta}f(t)=U(t)+iV(t)$ where $U(t)$ and $V(t) $ are real-valued functions. Then because R is real,

$$
R=\int_z^bU(t)dt\quad(3)
$$ 
But now,
$$
U(t)= Re\ e^{-i\theta}f(t) \le e^{-i\theta}f(t)=\vert f(t)\vert\quad(4)
$$
Therefore, from the properties of real integrals,
$$
\int_a^bU(t)dt\le\int\vert f(t)\vert dt
$$
which proves the desired result.

I have trouble figuring out how each of the numbered equations actually hold.
After writing the integral as $\int_a^bf(t)dt = Re^{i\theta}$ How can we say that (1) and (2) hold. (3) sort of makes sense as R has to be real.

Comment: Something is wrong here, you can't have both $\int_a^bf(t)dt = Re^{i\theta}$  and $R=\int_a^bf(t)dt$

Comment: @MyGlasses sorry, could you elaborate a little. Are the equations correct?

Comment: @EHH yeah, it bugs me too. Am I allowed to post the link to the notes here, it is written by a professor from a uni that i don't go to.

Comment: @MyGlasses, (2) has the extra $ e^{-i\theta} $, so they cant be right?

Comment: [link](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~jmf/Teaching/MT3/ComplexAnalysis.pdf) on page 26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that at the beginning is $|\int_a^b f(t)dt|=|Re^{i\theta}|$ and it would be ok. By the way, here's the  proof that I studied. It's basically the same proof, but maybe the notation is more clear.

Let $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ be such that
$$e^{i\alpha}\int_a^b f(t)dt \in \Bbb R^+$$
(I'm actually rotating $\int_a^b f(t)dt \in \Bbb C$).
So we get
$$e^{i\alpha}\int_a^b f(t)dt=\int_a^b e^{i\alpha}f(t)dt=\Re\left(\int_a^b e^{i\alpha}f(t)dt\right).$$
We conclude by
$$\left| \int_a^b f(t)dt\right|=\left|\int_a^b e^{i\alpha}f(t)dt\right|=\Re\left(\int_a^b e^{i\alpha}f(t)dt\right)=\int_a^b \Re(e^{i\alpha}f(t))dt\le \int_a^b |e^{i\alpha}f(t)|dt=\int_a^b |f(t)|dt$$
because $\Re(z) \le |z|$ by, sustantially, Pythagorean's Theorem.

Comment: Thank you, that is a very nice proof. Just 1 question, multiplying a complex number by $ e^{i\theta} $ rotates it?

Comment: Yes, use $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: This rotation of $\int f$ is pointwise, can we apply it for any interval?

Comment: $\int_a^b f(t) dt $ is a complex number